# Why is `_mm_stream_si128` much slower than `_mm_storeu_si128` on Skylake-Xeon when writing parts of 2 cache lines? But less effect on Haswell

Tags: performance, x86, intel, sse, intrinsics

I have code that looks like this (simple load, modify, store) (I've simplified it to make it more readable):

```
__asm__ __volatile__ ( "vzeroupper" : : : );
while(...) {
  __m128i in = _mm_loadu_si128(inptr);
  __m128i out = in; // real code does more than this, but I've simplified it
  _mm_stream_si12(outptr,out);
  inptr  += 12;
  outptr += 16;
}
```

This code runs about 5 times faster on our older <strike>Sandy Bridge</strike> Haswell hardware compared to our newer Skylake machines. For example, if the while loop runs about 16e9 iterations, it takes 14 seconds on <strike>Sandy Bridge</strike> Haswell and 70 seconds on Skylake.

We upgraded to the lasted microcode on the Skylake,
and also stuck in `vzeroupper` commands to avoid any AVX issues. Both fixes had no effect.

`outptr` is aligned to 16 bytes, so the `stream` command should be writing to aligned addresses. (I put in checks to verify this statement). `inptr` is not aligned by design. Commenting out the loads doesn't make any effect, the limiting commands are the stores.  `outptr` and `inptr` are pointing to different memory regions, there is no overlap.

If I replace the `_mm_stream_si128` with `_mm_storeu_si128`, the code runs way faster on both machines, about 2.9 seconds.

So the two questions are

1) why is there such a big difference between <strike>Sandy Bridge</strike> Haswell and Skylake when writing using the `_mm_stream_si128` intrinsic?

2) why does the `_mm_storeu_si128` run 5x faster than the streaming equivalent?

I'm a newbie when it comes to intrinsics.

---

**Addendum - test case**

Here is the entire test case: https://godbolt.org/z/toM2lB

Here is a summary of the benchmarks I took on two difference processors, E5-2680 v3 (Haswell) and 8180 (Skylake).

```
// icpc -std=c++14  -msse4.2 -O3 -DNDEBUG ../mre.cpp  -o mre
// The following benchmark times were observed on a Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8180 CPU @ 2.50GHz
// and Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 v3 @ 2.50GHz.
// The command line was
//    perf stat ./mre 100000
//
//   STORER               time (seconds)
//                     E5-2680   8180
// ---------------------------------------------------
//   _mm_stream_si128     1.65   7.29
//   _mm_storeu_si128     0.41   0.40
```

The ratio of *stream* to *store* is 4x or 18x, respectively.

I'm relying on the default `new` allocator to align my data to 16 bytes. I'm getting luck here that it is aligned.  I have tested that this is true, and in my production application, I use an aligned allocator to make absolutely sure it is, as well as checks on the address, but I left that off of the example because I don't think it matters.

**Second edit - 64B aligned output**

The comment from @Mystical made me check that the outputs were all cache aligned. The writes to the Tile structures are done in 64-B chunks, but the Tiles themselves were not 64-B aligned (only 16-B aligned).

So changed my test code like this:

```
#if 0
    std::vector<Tile> tiles(outputPixels/32);
#else
    std::vector<Tile, boost::alignment::aligned_allocator<Tile,64>> tiles(outputPixels/32);
#endif
```

and now the numbers are quite different:

```
//   STORER               time (seconds)
//                     E5-2680   8180
// ---------------------------------------------------
//   _mm_stream_si128     0.19   0.48
//   _mm_storeu_si128     0.25   0.52
```

So everything is much faster. But the Skylake is still slower than Haswell by a factor of 2.

**Third Edit. Purposely misalignment**

I tried the test suggested by @HaidBrais. I purposely allocated my vector class aligned to 64 bytes, then added 16 bytes or 32 bytes inside the allocator such that the allocation was either 16 Byte or 32 Byte aligned, but NOT 64 byte aligned. I also increased the number of loops to 1,000,000, and ran the test 3 times and picked the smallest time.

```
perf stat ./mre1  1000000
```

To reiterate, an alignment of 2^N means it is NOT aligned to 2^(N+1) or 2^(N+2).

```
//   STORER               alignment time (seconds)
//                        byte  E5-2680   8180
// ---------------------------------------------------
//   _mm_storeu_si128     16       3.15   2.69
//   _mm_storeu_si128     32       3.16   2.60
//   _mm_storeu_si128     64       1.72   1.71
//   _mm_stream_si128     16      14.31  72.14 
//   _mm_stream_si128     32      14.44  72.09 
//   _mm_stream_si128     64       1.43   3.38
```

So it is clear that cache alignment gives the best results, but `_mm_stream_si128` is better only on the 2680 processor and suffers some sort of penalty on the 8180 that I can't explain.

For furture use, here is the misaligned allocator I used (I did not templatize the misalignment, you'll have to edit the `32` and change to `0` or `16` as needed):

```
template <class T >
struct Mallocator {
  typedef T value_type;
    Mallocator() = default;
      template <class U> constexpr Mallocator(const Mallocator<U>&) noexcept 
{}
        T* allocate(std::size_t n) {
                if(n > std::size_t(-1) / sizeof(T)) throw std::bad_alloc();
                    uint8_t* p1 = static_cast<uint8_t*>(aligned_alloc(64, (n+1)*sizeof(T)));
                    if(! p1) throw std::bad_alloc();
                    p1 += 32; // misalign on purpose
                    return reinterpret_cast<T*>(p1);
                          }
          void deallocate(T* p, std::size_t) noexcept {
              uint8_t* p1 = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(p);
              p1 -= 32;
              std::free(p1); }
};
template <class T, class U>
bool operator==(const Mallocator<T>&, const Mallocator<U>&) { return true; }
template <class T, class U>
bool operator!=(const Mallocator<T>&, const Mallocator<U>&) { return false; }

...

std::vector<Tile, Mallocator<Tile>> tiles(outputPixels/32);
```

Comment: I forgot to say it explicitly, the improvement in time on the Skylake machine is 24x faster when switching intrinsics!

Comment: What types do your pointers have?  Is `+=16` doing 16 bytes, or 16 `int`s, or what?  (So are you doing full-line NT stores or are you striding).  What compiler are you using, and are you compiling with optimization enabled?

Comment: Are these benchmarks from this simplified partially-overlapping-copy code?  Can you at least link to a [mcve] of your microbenchmark on https://godbolt.org/ with the compiler options you used, so I can try it on my own Skylake?  (And profile it with `perf stat`)

Comment: Related: [Enhanced REP MOVSB for memcpy](//stackoverflow.com/q/43343231) for more about streaming stores vs. regular stores.

Comment: @petercordes I'm creating a compile-able example. The pointers are `char*`. I'm using the Intel icpc compiler, and `-O3` and `-msse4.2` optimization.

Comment: @MarkLakata - what Skylake CPU and how many sockets?

Comment: Processor is "Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8180 CPU @ 2.50GHz"

Comment: @PeterCordes Here is my MRE: https://godbolt.org/z/toM2lB

Comment: libstdc++'s `operator new` does align 16-byte aligned memory on x86-64 System V, and also Windows x64 I think, because `alignof(maxalign_t)` is 16.  So that part is fine.

Comment: I'm having trouble following the access pattern of the stores. But if it's not completely sequential and `tile` is not aligned to the cacheline, then NT stores will backfire in this case. In order for NT stores to do what you want them to, you need to fill entire cache lines. Any cache line that is split will take a very large penalty.

Comment: @Mysticial The stores are written in 64-byte (32 pixel) consecutive regions within the Tiles. But I did not check that the `std::vector<Tile>` is cache aligned. If it is not aligned, then I think those 64-bytes will be split on cache lines. Let me try that experiment to force the Tiles to be 64-byte aligned.

Comment: @Mystical see my update. Aligning the output to cache lines makes a difference. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: What happens when `tiles` is aligned on 32 and 16 byte boundaries? Note that `E5-2680 v3` is an HSX processor, not JKT. Regarding HSX vs. SKX, I'm suspecting that the performance on HSX is higher due to the higher single-threaded bandwidth compared to SKX. You can check using the Intel MLC tool by running the command `mlc --max_bandwidth -mN` where `N` is a core number that is different from 0 and the number of the sibling thread of core 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplified code doesn't really show the actual structure of your benchmark. I don't think the simplified code will exhibit the slowness you've mentioned.

The actual loop from your godbolt code is:

```
while (count > 0)
        {
            // std::cout << std::hex << (void*) ptr << " " << (void*) tile <<std::endl;
            __m128i value0 = _mm_loadu_si128(reinterpret_cast<const __m128i*>(ptr + 0 * diffBytes));
            __m128i value1 = _mm_loadu_si128(reinterpret_cast<const __m128i*>(ptr + 1 * diffBytes));
            __m128i value2 = _mm_loadu_si128(reinterpret_cast<const __m128i*>(ptr + 2 * diffBytes));
            __m128i value3 = _mm_loadu_si128(reinterpret_cast<const __m128i*>(ptr + 3 * diffBytes));

            __m128i tileVal0 = value0;
            __m128i tileVal1 = value1;
            __m128i tileVal2 = value2;
            __m128i tileVal3 = value3;

            STORER(reinterpret_cast<__m128i*>(tile + ipixel + diffPixels * 0), tileVal0);
            STORER(reinterpret_cast<__m128i*>(tile + ipixel + diffPixels * 1), tileVal1);
            STORER(reinterpret_cast<__m128i*>(tile + ipixel + diffPixels * 2), tileVal2);
            STORER(reinterpret_cast<__m128i*>(tile + ipixel + diffPixels * 3), tileVal3);

            ptr    += diffBytes * 4;
            count  -= diffBytes * 4;
            tile   += diffPixels * 4;
            ipixel += diffPixels * 4;
            if (ipixel == 32)
            {
                // go to next tile
                ipixel = 0;
                tileIter++;
                tile = reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(tileIter->pixels);
            }
        }
```

Note the `if (ipixel == 32)` part. This jumps to a different tile every time `ipixel` reaches 32. Since `diffPixels` is 8, this happens *every* iteration. Hence you are only making 4 streaming stores (64 bytes) per tile. Unless each tile happens to be 64-byte aligned, which is unlikely to happen by chance and cannot be relied on, this means that every write writes to only part of two different cache lines. That's a known anti-pattern for streaming stores: for effective use of streaming stores you need to write out the full line.

On to the performance differences: streaming stores have widely varying performance on different hardware. These stores always occupy a line fill buffer for some time, but how long varies: on lots of client chips it seems to only occupy a buffer for about the L3 latency. I.e., once the streaming store reaches the L3 it can be handed off (the L3 will track the rest of the work) and the LFB can be freed on the core. Server chips often have much longer latency. Especially multi-socket hosts.

Evidently, the performance of NT stores is worse on the SKX box, and *much* worse for partial line writes. The overall worse performance is probably related to the redesign of the L3 cache.

Comment: *Each tile happens to be 64-byte aligned* I think you mean misaligned.  `ipixel = 0` every time the store runs, so if it were aligned you'd be doing a full-line write.  (Like the OP found when they switched from `new` to `aligned_alloc` or something and mostly fixed the performance bug in their code.)

Comment: @PeterCordes yeah, thanks - it was missing an "unless" at the start of the sentence.

Comment: Possibly worth pointing out that GNU/Linux `new` and `malloc` are almost guaranteed *not* to make that happen for large allocations, normally allocating multiple pages and using the first 16 bytes for bookkeeping, then returning a pointer that's page-aligned + 16.  When carving up a page into multiple smaller allocations you might get lucky, like maybe every 4th line I guess.

Comment: @PeterCordes - sure, but does it matter? It just means you get lucky less often - you pretty much want to ensure you are asking for aligned allocations with such a huge perf glass jaw lurking, and understanding how some `malloc` behaves internally seems like it is going down the wrong path.

Comment: I added "which is unlikely to happen by chance and cannot be relied on" rather than any glibc specific details.

Comment: That's fair.  I just meant as an explanation for observed performance, to estimate how "lucky" the naive benchmark might have gotten, and thus what fraction of the 64-byte chunks were full-line writes.  And also to reinforce that large allocations always give worst-case results, thus using aligned allocators is important in practice right now, not just for future safety.  Much code tends to just use unaligned loads/stores because there's little penalty, but I suspect some people don't realize that glibc `malloc` *always* gives them misalignment for 32-byte or wider vectors, for large buffers.

Comment: @PeterCordes - is the OP on Linux?

Comment: Some kind of Unix/Linux.  They ran `icpc` with `-o mre` not `-o mre.exe` on their SKX system.

Comment: @PeterCordes - I don't know why someone who didn't know about the mmap threshold behavior (I confirm that I [reproduced that locally](https://gist.github.com/travisdowns/72d6c270751b62f8d993a82989403ca0)) would assume you needed aligned allocators only for "future safety" - after all, the reasonable assumption would be something like arbitrarily aligned 16-byte allocations which would give you a bad alignment 75% of the time.

Comment: You mean starting from the time the LFB is evicted until it becomes free for reuse, this latency is about the L3 latency? I've not measured this particular latency before, but my understanding is that the LFB that holds a UC line can be freed as soon as it is accepted by the L2 (i.e., the request gets accepted and an SQ entry has been allocated for it), not the L3. Is there are specific reason why it has to reach the L3? The way to measure to this would be checking how long it takes for an LFB to become free, but this still doesn't tell us for sure why; there could be other reasons.

Comment: @HadiBrais - yeah, I am not sure. I observed that calculated latency assuming a concurrency of 10-12 was approximately the L3 latency, but you are right that this doesn't imply the LFB needs to be held for the entire duration, it could return as soon as it allocates in the SQ, as you point out. I was doing "steady state" tests, i.e., lots of stores, and the effect ends up being mostly the same there: whatever the bottleneck ends up being, it propagates back to the LFBs eventually: so the LFB occupancy time will become long, in the steady state ....

Comment: ... not necessarily because the LFB needs to be held the whole time, but because there are not SQ resources (which in turn may because of no downstream resources, e.g., in the memory controller and so on). I guess you'd have to do a non-steady state test to see how long the LFB is occupied for. One idea is to check how long a load to the same address forwards for: e.g., a full line of NT stores followed by a load should forward as long as the LFB is available, but once it leaves the LFB, I guess the latency may suddenly shoot up if it's chasing the line to memory (not sure about it).

Comment: The latency depends on the exact implementation of the transactions between the L1 and L2. In one possible design, the L1 first sends a request without the data to check whether the L2 can accept the request., If the L2 accepts the request, it will response to the L1 with a message, then the L1 puts the data on the bus (the number of messages required to do this depends on whether it's a partial line or full line transaction and the width and protocl (see below) of the bus; fully lines use burst transactions but partial lines are evicted using multiple transactions)...

Comment: ...As soon as the last byte is put on the bus, the LFB could become free for reuse, even though the data is till in-flight and has not been fully written into the SQ's entry allocated for it. If L2 rejected the request for whatever reason, the L1 will have to retry according to a retry mechanism. The deallocation latency will definitely be (much) larger than one cycle in this design, even if the L1-L2 bus is fully pipelined. In the other possible design, the L1 sends the request and the data (some part of the data depending on the characteristics of the request and the bus) to the L2...

Comment: ...If the L2 accepts the request and if the bus width is 32 or 64 bytes, then it could take as little as 2 or 1 cycles to deallocate the LFB. Either way, for partial line transactions, it will always take many more cycles than full line transactions. Also for partial lines, it depends on the distribution of valid bytes in the line whether the bus supports "valid byte bits" similar to the LFB. However, potentially for reliability reasons, the LFB will not be deallocated until all of the data reaches the L2...

Comment: That is, it's not enough to put the last byte on the bus; the last byte has to be written into the SQ. The L2 would then send a message to the L1 that it can now deallcoate the LFB.

Comment: Regarding HSX vs. SKX, is there something specific about the different design of the L3 cache that you can think of that can be the reason for the diff in perf so that the OP can perhaps test this using perf counters? My theory is that the single-core bandwidth on HSX is better than SKX.

Comment: @HadiBrais - well I measure the L3 bandwidth as much lower in SKX, something around 6 bytes/cycle, probably due to the new design (since it is no longer inclusive, for a test that fits in L3 but not L2, we expect a lot of data movement from L2 to L3 for victims, unlike earlier designs where we could expect a silent castout from L2). Also the latency is a lot larger. Those factors could add up to a 2x difference shown for the full-line writes. Why it got way worse for partial line writes, I am not sure.

Comment: If it makes any difference at this point, the OP (me) uses Linux Centos 7.3 (for Skylake) and 7.0 (Haswell. E5-2680 v3). I am going to go back and change all references to SandyBridge to Haswell, my naive mistake.

Comment: @BeeOnRope all systems are 2 sockets.  I also tested two other system (all with 2 sockets) one with a `Intel(R) Xeon(R) Silver 4214 CPU @ 2.20GHz` and the other with a `Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8160 CPU @ 2.10GHz`, and the results were like the SKX: ~70 seconds for the misaligned streaming instructions.

Comment: @MarkLakata, thanks. I can't say exactly what changed wrt the partial NT writes. There are obviously some tradeoffs there: the CPU has to "guess" when the write is partial: i.e., it shouldn't assume the write is partial too early and flush the fill buffer, because maybe the code just hasn't gotten around to writing it yet. OTOH you don't want to leave too many open since it disadvantages other code running concurrently (including on the other logical core) that may be want to use the fill buffers. So maybe the heuristics changed in SKX and this hurts the partial write case.

Comment: It is also possible that something outside of the core changed, e.g., the way partial writes are in the outer caching levels and at the memory controller. It isn't even clear how it works on existing chips: if you write a full line, that line can just go down as far as it wants towards memory, invalidating itself in any cache levels. A partial line is different: at some point it needs to read the existing value of the line, in order to fill in (merge) the unwritten bytes together with the written ones. This could happen anywhere from the core itself to DRAM.