# _mm_stream_si128 is 2000% slower than _mm_store_si128

Tags: c, simd, sse2

I was writing some C code to make a random number generator, and used the following code:

```
// header
typedef struct {
    uint64_t values[2];
} fy5z_state_t;
fy5z_state_t fy5z_seed(uint64_t seed_value);

uint64_t fy5z_generate(fy5z_state_t* state);
// source
fy5z_state_t fy5z_seed(uint64_t seed_value)
{
    fy5z_state_t state;
    state.values[0] = (seed_value & 0xFFFFFFFF);
    state.values[1] = (seed_value & (0xFFFFFFFF << 31)) + seed_value;
    return state;
}

uint64_t fy5z_generate(fy5z_state_t* state)
{
    __m128i got_data = _mm_load_si128((__m128i const*)(state->values));
    __m128i shuffled = _mm_shuffle_epi32(got_data, 0x8d);
    __m128i final_add = _mm_add_epi8 (shuffled, got_data);
    _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)(state->values), final_add);
    return state->values[0];
}
```

Additionally, the following code is used to time the performance:

```
#ifndef TRIAL_COUNT
#define TRIAL_COUNT 1024 * 1024 * 10
#endif

static void print_time_us(const char* name, void(*fn)(void))
{
    struct timespec start, end;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &start);
    fn();
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &end);
    uint64_t delta_us = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000000 + (end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) / 1000;
    printf("Running: '%s' took %llu u/s\n", name, delta_us);
}

static void test_fy5z(void) {
    fy5z_state_t fseed = fy5z_seed(0xfab5381);
    unsigned long total = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < TRIAL_COUNT; ++i)
    {
        total += fy5z_generate(&fseed);
    }
}
```

Something I discovered is, in the generator function, if `_mm_store_si128` is used, I get: `Running: 'fy5z' took 113328 u/s` , but if I swap that with `_mm_stream_si128` , I get `Running: 'fy5z' took 1956792 u/s` .

This is on a MacOS 2.7 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7

Why is `store` so much faster than `stream` in this use case ?

Comment: That’s for _mm_storeu_si128 , this question is for _mm_store_si128. This is for the aligned version

Comment: Because _mm_stream_si128 doesn't use the cache?

Comment: `_mm_store_si128` (`movdqa [mem], xmm`) is exactly the same speed as `movdqu` when the pointer happens to be aligned (on Nehalem and later, i.e. since the very first-gen i7 in 2009), which is also a requirement for `movntdq`.  That objection to [Why is \`\_mm\_stream\_si128\` much slower than \`\_mm\_storeu\_si128\` on Skylake-Xeon when writing parts of 2 cache lines? But less effect on Haswell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57420025) doesn't make sense.  And yeah, it's similar, except you're actually *reloading* the NT store to return it, so that's even worse.

Comment: What CPU *do* you have?  And don't just say "i7", that tells us basically nothing.  e.g. I have an i7-6700k, which is a Skylake.  (Note that a quad-core is very different from a Xeon in terms of uncore latency, especially for Skylake, but Bee's answer does mention some general things about partial-line NT stores being an anti-pattern, and you're not storing 64 bytes total. Even worse, you're reloading it from the same thread, which could have benefited from cache / store-forwarding.)